# Generate Numbers VB.NET

Tags: vb.net, matrix, minesweeper

So I'm developing a minesweeper game and i've assigned the mines, but I've got to generate the numbers around them. I've already developed the code, but it doesnt seem to be working.
It's important to refer that I'm using a DataGridView.

Here's how my code looks like now:

Declaring my variables:

```
Public line As Integer
Public column As Integer
Public numbandeiras As Integer
Public mat(11, 11) As Integer
Public Const MINASEXISTE = 34
Public jogo(11, 11) As Integer
```

Initializing the mines:

```
Public Sub initflags()

    'initialize the matrix
    For i = 0 To 11
        For j = 0 To 11
            mat(i, j) = 0
        Next
    Next


    'generate the mines
    Do Until numbandeiras = MINASEXISTE



        'Randomize()
        line = Int(Rnd() * 10) + 1
        column = Int(Rnd() * 10) + 1
        r = line
        c = column
        If mat(line, column) = 0 Then
            numbandeiras = numbandeiras + 1


            mat(line, column) = 1

        End If

    Loop

'call numbers    
Call avisinhos()

End Sub
```

Generating the numbers around the mines:

```
 Public Sub avisinhos()

    'declaring my local variables
    Dim conta As Integer = 0
    Dim linestart As Integer = -1
    Dim lineend As Integer = 1
    Dim colstart As Integer = -1
    Dim colend As Integer = 1
    Dim auxlinha, auxcolumn As Integer


  'generating the numbers in the matrix
    For auxlinha = 1 To 10
        For auxcolumn = 1 To 10
            While conta < MINASEXISTE
                If mat(line, column) = 1 Then 'tem uma mina


                    mat(auxlinha - 1, auxcolumn - 1) = mat(auxlinha - 1, auxcolumn - 1) + 1
                    mat(auxlinha - 1, auxcolumn) = mat(auxlinha - 1, auxcolumn) + 1
                    mat(auxlinha - 1, auxcolumn + 1) = mat(auxlinha - 1, auxcolumn + 1) + 1
                    mat(auxlinha, auxcolumn - 1) = mat(auxlinha, auxcolumn - 1) + 1
                    mat(auxlinha, auxcolumn + 1) = mat(auxlinha, auxcolumn + 1) + 1
                    mat(auxlinha + 1, auxcolumn - 1) = mat(auxlinha + 1, auxcolumn - 1) + 1
                    mat(auxlinha + 1, auxcolumn) = mat(auxlinha + 1, auxcolumn) + 1
                    mat(auxlinha + 1, auxcolumn + 1) = mat(auxlinha + 1, auxcolumn + 1) + 1
                End If

                conta = conta + 1
            End While
        Next
    Next

End Sub
End Module
```

Atributing the right images to it's matrix number on the DataGridView tablw:

```
 Private Sub tab1_CellContentClick(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As    System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewCellEventArgs) Handles tab1.CellContentClick
    My.Computer.Audio.Play("butao.wav")
    Dim r, c As Integer
    r = tab1.CurrentCell.RowIndex + 1
    c = tab1.CurrentCell.ColumnIndex + 1
    Label5.Text = "linha=" + Str(r)
    Label6.Text = "coluna=" + Str(c)
    'MessageBox.Show(minas(r, c))


    If (jogo(r, c) = 1) Then
        MessageBox.Show("Ja jogou")
    Else
    'When There is a bomb
        If mat(r, c) = 1 Then
            Me.tab1.Rows(r - 1).Cells(c - 1).Value = Image.FromFile("mina1.png")
            jogo(r, c) = 1
            player1 = player1 + 3
            Label1.Text = Val(player1)
        End If
      'When There is a number
        If mat(r, c) > 1 Then
            Call preenche_num(r - 1, c - 1)
      'When there is nothing
        End If
        If mat(r, c) = 0 Then
            Me.tab1.Rows(r - 1).Cells(c - 1).Value = Image.FromFile("vazio.png")
        End If

    End If
End Sub
```

Diferent number possibilities:

```
 Sub preenche_num(ByVal r As Integer, ByVal c As Integer)

    Select Case mat(r, c)
        Case 2
            Me.tab1.Rows(r).Cells(c).Value = Image.FromFile("um.png")
        Case 3
            Me.tab1.Rows(r).Cells(c).Value = Image.FromFile("dois.png")
        Case 4
            Me.tab1.Rows(r).Cells(c).Value = Image.FromFile("tres.png")
        Case 5
            Me.tab1.Rows(r).Cells(c).Value = Image.FromFile("quatro.png")
        Case 6
            Me.tab1.Rows(r).Cells(c).Value = Image.FromFile("cinco.png")
        Case 7
            Me.tab1.Rows(r).Cells(c).Value = Image.FromFile("seis.png")
        Case 8
            Me.tab1.Rows(r).Cells(c).Value = Image.FromFile("sete.png")
        Case 9
            Me.tab1.Rows(r).Cells(c).Value = Image.FromFile("oito.png")
    End Select
End Sub
```

I do believe that my error is somewhere where I generate the numbers.
Best regards, joao.

Comment: What exactly is your problem? What doesn't work? Did you write any tests? What do they say? Are you getting an exception? Unexpected results? It is very difficult to answer this question without more specific details about your problem.

Comment: Everything works fine, I'm able to generate the flags but the numbers aroud them won't appear. The compiler gives me no errors.

Comment: Why don't you try solve what they say then?? By the way you said VB.NET as a tag but you just do procedural programming and you use old or odd syntax at places.

Comment: I recommend to try to track down the exact part of your code that doesn't seem to work as expected. Then post that part only. I'm aware that this might be difficult since your code is procedural, but it will be easier for us to help if we don't have to wade through all the code ourselves.

Answer (score 2):

You are using `auxlinha` and `auxcolumn` in your loops:

```
For auxlinha = 1 To 10
  For auxcolumn = 1 To 10
```

But then you are using `line` and `column` to check the item inside the loop:

```
    If mat(line, column) = 1 Then 'tem uma mina
```

Also, when you have fixed that, your algorithm will still fail miserably. You are writing in the same array that you are reading, and writing ahead of the position where you read. A `1` means a mine in the initial array, but once you start increasing the squares around a mine, you no longer know if `1` means a mine or if it means that there is a mine close to that square.

Also, you are looping from 1 to 10, so no mines along the edges will be considered. You have to loop all the squares, and check if you are at a border when you increase the surrounding squares.

Answer (score 0):

**First** remark: **program in English!**

We cannot read your code. If the identifiers aren’t important, you’ve done something wrong: they *should* be important in helping to understand the code. English is the language of programming – embrace this.

**Secondly**, having 2–9 to stand for the number 1–8 is a bit unintuitive and error-prone, don’t you think?

If you insist on encoding all possible values by numbers, make mines –1, and the numbers represent themselves.

**Third**, on debugging: you suspect that the generation of the numbers doesn’t work. Well, this is easy to test: just hard-code some numbers and look whether the display works then. Or do it the other way round, calculate the numbers and output them in the debug window.

**Fourth**, on style. Make your life easier by declaring variables on first use, *not before*. Having blocks of variable declaration at the beginning doesn’t make the code clearer. I also suspect that you should enable `Option Explicit` and `Option Strict`. I’d also remove the remnants of VB6 style: e.g. `Call` is unnecessary, and `Str` and `Val` should be dropped in favour of .NET methods.